# How can I obfuscate only com.foo.* and com.bar.* (ProGuard)?

Tags: obfuscation, proguard

I want to obfuscate only some packages:

```
com.foo.*
com.bar.*
```

I have tried

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class **, !com.foo.**, !com.bar.** { *; }
```

and

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class !com.foo.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class !com.bar.** { *; }
```

In both cases the classes from com.foo.* and com.bar.* was *NOT* obfuscated.

Answer (score 49):

This should work

```
-keep class !com.foo.**,!com.bar.** { *; }
```

You can find a summary of the various -keep options at
https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage#keepoptions

You can find the explanation of ProGuard's regular expressions at
https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage#filters

Comment: In my Android project this lines do nothing. What can block it?

Comment: @rekire Maybe you haven't set "minifyEnabled true" in build.gradle?

Comment: In Android, this works for me `-keep class !com.foo.**,!com.bar.**, ** { *; }`.
Need to add pattern what you want to keep `**` - means everything