# Android proguard obfuscate few classes only

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

I am using proguard in my app and I want to obfuscate only 4 classes as rest of them are model classes. But when I am trying to use: 
-keep class !com.abc.**,!com.def.** { *; }, its not obfuscating these classes .

Can anyone suggest how to use the "!" operator to obfuscate selected classes only.

I cannot maintain a list of all the other classes and keep mentioning them in the proguard to keep them and neither I can put all of the model classes in one package because of some design restrictions. Hence, I want to use the "!" operator to obfuscate my 4 classes.

I referred [How can I obfuscate only com.foo.* and com.bar.* (ProGuard)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536016/how-can-i-obfuscate-only-com-foo-and-com-bar-proguard) and it did not help.

Thanks in advance.